# How to optimize this simulation in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I am trying to do a multi threading simulation in Java and I have managed to do it with a queue but the execution time is high, any ideas on how I could optimize this? Can using recursion save time?

The input has to be like this:

- 2 5 It means that there are two threads(workers) for 5 jobs
- 1 2 3 4 5 This is the jobs that are an integer which means the time cost of processing that job so the output will be this:
- 0 0 The two threads try to simultaneously take jobs from the list, so thread with index 0 actually
- 1 0 takes the first job and starts working on it at the moment 0
- 0 1 After 1 second, thread 0 is done with the first job and takes the third job from the list, and starts processing it immediately at time 1.
- 1 2 One second later, thread 1 is done with the second job and takes the fourth job from the list, and starts processing it immediately at time 2
- 0 4 Finally, after 2 more seconds, thread 0 is done with the third job and takes the fifth job from the list, and starts processing it immediately at time 4

This is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class JobQueue {
    private int numWorkers;
    private int[] jobs;
    private int[] assignedWorker;
    private long[] startTime;

    private FastScanner in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new JobQueue().solve();
    }

    private void readData() throws IOException {
        numWorkers = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        jobs = new int[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            jobs[i] = in.nextInt(); 
        }
    }

    private void writeResponse() {
        for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; ++i) {
            out.println(assignedWorker[i] + " " + startTime[i]);
        }
    }

    private void assignJobs() {
        // TODO: replace this code with a faster algorithm.
        assignedWorker = new int[jobs.length];
         startTime = new long[jobs.length];
         PriorityQueue<Integer> nextTimesQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
         HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> workersReadyAtTimeT = new HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>>();
         long[] nextFreeTime = new long[numWorkers];
         int duration = 0;
         int bestWorker = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
          duration = jobs[i];
          if(i<numWorkers) {
            bestWorker = i;
            nextTimesQueue.add(duration);
            addToSet(workersReadyAtTimeT, duration, i,0);
          }else {
            int currentTime = nextTimesQueue.poll();
            Set<Integer> workersReady = workersReadyAtTimeT.get(currentTime);
            if (workersReady.size()>1) { 
              bestWorker = workersReady.iterator().next();
              workersReady.remove(bestWorker);
              workersReadyAtTimeT.remove(currentTime);
              workersReadyAtTimeT.put(currentTime,workersReady);
              nextTimesQueue.add(currentTime);
            } else {
              bestWorker = workersReady.iterator().next();
              workersReadyAtTimeT.remove(currentTime);
              nextTimesQueue.add(currentTime+duration);
              addToSet(workersReadyAtTimeT, duration, bestWorker, currentTime);
            }
          }
          
          assignedWorker[i] = bestWorker;
          startTime[i] = nextFreeTime[bestWorker];
          nextFreeTime[bestWorker] += duration;
         }
        }
    
    private void addToSet(HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> workersReadyAtTimeT, int duration, int worker, int current) {
        if(workersReadyAtTimeT.get(current+duration)==null) {
          HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
          s.add(worker);
          workersReadyAtTimeT.put(current+duration, s);
        }else {
          Set<Integer> s = workersReadyAtTimeT.get(current+duration);
          s.add(worker);
          workersReadyAtTimeT.put(current+duration,s);
         }
        }

    public void solve() throws IOException {
        in = new FastScanner();
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));
        readData();
        assignJobs();
        writeResponse();
        out.close();
    }

    static class FastScanner {
        private BufferedReader reader;
        private StringTokenizer tokenizer;

        public FastScanner() {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            tokenizer = null;
        }

        public String next() throws IOException {
            while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
            }
            return tokenizer.nextToken();
        }

        public int nextInt() throws IOException {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please re-format your question, so that the many contiguous numbers gain some meaning?

Comment: Do the jobs have to be processed in the order they're in `jobList`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your `jobsList` object is completely redundant, everything it contains is also in the `jobs` array and when you take the front element you get the item at `jobs[i]`. To speed up *a little* you could take the constructors of the ints out of the loop and just assign new numbers to them. Another optimization would be to not search during the first `numWorkers` jobs because you know you still have idle workers until you have exausted your pool. Once you have found one good worker you dont have to keep looking so you can `continue` out of your for-loop.

```
public class JobQueue {
private int numWorkers;
private int[] jobs;
private int[] assignedWorker;
private long[] startTime;

    private void readData() throws IOException {
    numWorkers = in.nextInt();
    int m = in.nextInt();
    jobs = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        jobs[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
}

private void assignJobs() {
    assignedWorker = new int[jobs.length];
    startTime = new long[jobs.length];
    long[] nextFreeTime = new long[numWorkers];
    int duration = 0;
    int bestWorker = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
        duration = jobs[i];
        bestWorker = 0;
        if (i< numWorkers){
            bestWorker= i;
        } else{
            for (int j = 0; j < numWorkers; ++j) {
                if (nextFreeTime[j] < nextFreeTime[bestWorker])
                    bestWorker = j;
                    continue;
            }
        }
        assignedWorker[i] = bestWorker;
        startTime[i] = nextFreeTime[bestWorker];
        nextFreeTime[bestWorker] += duration;
    }
}
```

However, both your solution and this slightly trimmed down one take 2 milliseconds to run. I also looked at having HashMap to maintain a NextWorker marker but at some point you catch up with it and end up looking everytime for the next one and don't win much.

You could try having an ordered List/Queue, but then you have expensive inserts instead of expensive searches, and you have to kee track of the timeslice. But a version like that could look like this:

```
private void assignJobs() {

 assignedWorker = new int[jobs.length];
 startTime = new long[jobs.length];
 PriorityQueue<Integer> nextTimesQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
 HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> workersReadyAtTimeT = new HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>>();
 long[] nextFreeTime = new long[numWorkers];
 int duration = 0;
 int bestWorker = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
  duration = jobs[i];
  if(i<numWorkers) {
    bestWorker = i;
    nextTimesQueue.add(duration);
    addToSet(workersReadyAtTimeT, duration, i,0);
  }else {
    int currentTime = nextTimesQueue.poll();
    Set<Integer> workersReady = workersReadyAtTimeT.get(currentTime);
    if (workersReady.size()>1) { 
      bestWorker = workersReady.iterator().next();
      workersReady.remove(bestWorker);
      workersReadyAtTimeT.remove(currentTime);
      workersReadyAtTimeT.put(currentTime,workersReady);
      nextTimesQueue.add(currentTime);
    } else {
      bestWorker = workersReady.iterator().next();
      workersReadyAtTimeT.remove(currentTime);
      nextTimesQueue.add(currentTime+duration);
      addToSet(workersReadyAtTimeT, duration, bestWorker, currentTime);
    }
  }
  assignedWorker[i] = bestWorker;
  startTime[i] = nextFreeTime[bestWorker];
  nextFreeTime[bestWorker] += duration;
 }
}

private void addToSet(HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> workersReadyAtTimeT, int duration, int worker, int current) {
if(workersReadyAtTimeT.get(current+duration)==null) {
  HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
  s.add(worker);
  workersReadyAtTimeT.put(current+duration, s);
}else {
  Set<Integer> s = workersReadyAtTimeT.get(current+duration);
  s.add(worker);
  workersReadyAtTimeT.put(current+duration,s);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I don't know why I have a NullPointerException with large numbers like 4 workers for 12 jobs

Comment: Are you using a scanner to put in your values? I used `in = new Scanner("4 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12");` and have no issues with null pointers. it also still runs in 2 milliseconds for me.

Comment: Oh I see that the exception is launched only when there are two or more jobs with the same value like 1 x12 or 1 2 1 2 1 2... How could i fix this?

Comment: Sorry but with `in = new Scanner("4 12 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1");` I still don't get an error. Are you sure you have the right number of parameters?

Comment: I writed the full code just in case I have something wrong, the exception is launched in the line 54: if (workersReady.size()>1) {

Comment: Have you fixed this now? you do not init your scanner with any values: `in = new FastScanner();` so its empty.